# Custom non standard year range of datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I wish to use the functionality of the jquery datepicker however I want my year range to be a custom range e.g.

```
Year 2, Year 1, Current
```

Where the values for these would be something like:

```
2,1,0
```

Is there a way to do this via the jquery datepicker?  I've tried setting the yearrange to "Year 1:Current" but it doesn't seem to accept that.

Comment: How would you then want the output? if for instance the date was 09-16-2010 it would not make any sense if the output was 09-16-1

Comment: Ok, I guess the underlying value could still be a date but I want the user to only see Year 1, Year 2 etc

Comment: So what year would year 2 and year 1 be equal to? It's definately not in the standard datepicker, but it could possibly be manipulated after the datepicker has been initialized.

Comment: I guess Current would be equal to the current year, year 1 would be now() + 1 etc